# Find point on a parallel line(slanted lines) with distance d from start points

Tags: geometry

I have two parallel slanted lines, with

- one line with know set of start and end points.(x1,y1,x2,y2)
- Second line with only know start points (x3,y3), end points are of distance d2 from the start.
- I the know distance between the two parallel lines, distance d1 & d2.

  -now how to find the points x4 and y4 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the twi lines are parallel, they have common angular coefficents, so
$$m_1=m_2$$
This is important because we can write the equation of the second line as:
$$y=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}x$$
because we suppose the second line passing throught $O(0,0)$.
Let $\Delta y=y_3-y_4$ and $\Delta x=x_3-x_4$.By Pythagora's theorem, we have:
$$d_2=\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$$
So, to find the coords of $(x_4,y_4)$, we have to solve the following equation:
$$\sqrt{(x_3-x_4)^2+(y_3-y_4)^2}=d_2$$
In particular, here $x_3$ and $y_3$ are known, while $y_4$ van be written in terms of $c_4$, in fact:
$$y_4=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}x_4$$
Squaring both sides and letting $m=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}, x_4=x$, we arrive at:
$$x^2(m^2+1)-2x(x_3+my_3)+x_3^2+y_3^2-d_2^2=0$$
And so:
$$x=x_4=\frac{2(x_3+my_3)\pm\sqrt{(x_3+my_3)^2-4(m^2+1)(x_3^2+y_3^2-d_2^2)}}{2(m^2+1)}$$

Comment: could you describe the final equation?

Comment: @Balaram26: please see my edits.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Though the answer works, i have few thousand points similar to x4,y4 ,so using this equation seems more complex as applying it for every line would take more time.